# Hiding dynamic classes with jQuery and a select element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to hide a div on my page based on what class it has, I also have a select element with options in it.

So just so you know I have a template that lists database results and then uses a while loop to loop every row, there is a column in my database that contains all of the 'Make's' for each row.

Here is the example of that code:

```
<?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '
        <div class="listing-container ' . $row["Make"] . '">
          <a href="carpage.php"><h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">'.$row["Make"].' '.$row["Model"].' '.$row["Variant"].'</h3></a>
          <h3 class="price-listing">£'.number_format($row['Price']).'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
         <img src="'.(explode(',', $row["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" class="stock-img-finder"/>
          <div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
              <li class="diesel-svg list-svg">'.$row["FuelType"].'</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg list-svg">'.$row["Bodytype"].'</li>
              <li class="gear-svg list-svg">'.$row["Transmission"].'</li>
              <li class="color-svg list-svg">'.$row["Colour"].'</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style checked-btn hover-listing-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> History checked 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style more-details-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> More details 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style test-drive-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="test-drive-glyph"></span> Test drive 
          </button>
          <h4 class="h4-style listing-photos-count"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 5 More photos</h4>
        </div>
          ';
      } ?>
```

Take note of this div "", it includes the make of the SQL row in the class.

Here is an example of my select element:

```
<select class="form-control select-box">
             <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
             <?php while($make = $filterres->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
             echo '
             <option value='.$make["Make"].'>'.$make["Make"].'</option>
             ';
             } ?>
</select>
```

All the 'Make's' are looped and do not show duplicates.

I am using this jQuery at the moment to hide all of the classes that are called 'AUDI'.

```
var myContainers = $("div[class^='listing-container ']").not(".listing-container.AUDI");
myContainers.hide();
myContainers.next(".listing-container-spec").hide();
```

I now want the select element to determine what 'Make's' are shown, for example if the user selects BMW I only want the listing-container div's that have the class of BMW.

Can someone show me an example of how this could possibly work and explain it to me? I'm still incredibly nooby with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make != 'make-any'){
      $('.makes').hide();
      $('.'+make).show();
      } else {
        $('.makes').show();
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select-box">
             <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
             <option value='BMW' selected>BMW</option>
              <option value='AUDI'>AUDI</option>
</select>
<div class="BMW makes">BWM Stuff</div>
<div class="AUDI makes" style="display: none;">AUDI Stuff</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried your method however it isn't functioning on my live site, I've checked the code and everything looks fine.

I hate to be cheeky but here is the page if you would be kind enough to have a quick look:http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.php

Comment: The concole logs `Uncaught ReferenceError: MasterSlider is not defined ` so no JS will run. You must have some variable MasterSlider that is not setup right.

Comment: It also looks like you are loading the jQuery lib twice in your page.

Comment: `var slider = new MasterSlider();` I don't know what plugin MasterSlider is, but if you remove the slider stuff it should work.

Comment: I have removed it on the live site and still no luck :( any other ideas?

Comment: `<option value=AUDI>AUDI</option>` I think you need quotes around the values

Comment: Right I see, I've changed it and still no luck ha this is killing me!

Comment: Add `alert(make);` after the `var make...` line to see if in fact the listener is firing.

Comment: Oh. duh. You need to add a `makes` class to all the divs you want to hide. Or change `makes` to `listing-container` in the JS. However looking at your HTML that will only hide the titles. The spec is a different class. If you want to discuess furhter we can in chat. You are going to have to make additional changes for model as well.

Comment: Fantastic help I cant thank you enough for helping me through that!